# Backbone collection inside model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and I wonder if there is a way to save previous models in a collection as an attribute of the model itself. For example,

```
var history = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
         id: '',
         name: '',
         history: history //history is a collection of myModel
          },

  //override setter so when set method is called, it will save the previous model inside history collection.

})
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be ephemeral history

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({    
    defaults:{
        id:''
    },
    constructor: function(){
       this.history = new Backbone.Collection();
    },

    set: function(){
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      this.history.add(this.toJSON());
      return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, args);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: history is not a constructor at this.history = new history();  I changed it to History() but that didn't help.

Comment: I can't find `history` in the docs either. What are we trying to do here? There is something called [previous](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-previous) though

Comment: @manu29.d I know there is previous but previous only have the previous value of a changed attribute. What I wanted is a list/collection of previous changed attributes. For example, the model starts out empty, if i change something, i would add that to "history". Then if I change the model again, "history" would have the 2 previous changed attributes/model.